# page refreshing instead of displaying ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I realise this might be a duplicate but I have been looking at this for 2 hours and can not find what I am doing wrong and looking at other posts is not showing my error.

I am having a challenge with handling the JSON returned in an AJAX call under CodeIgniter.  I am new to AJAX and I am adapting this from things I have read and other self-teaching.  Everything is working well except that instead of displaying result messages in a div, my page is refreshing and showing the JSON in raw text.

```
function makeAjaxCall(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/testing/index.php/urlsaving/jquery_save",
        cache: false,
        data: $('#frm').serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        type: "post",
        success: function( data ){
            $('#validation-error').html(data.msg);
        //have tried 'return false;' here to halt the default action
        }
    });
}
```

This is the form from which the request is sent and where I want the return data displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>URL saving sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="adding_urls">
    <form action="http://localhost/testing/index.php/urlsaving/jquery_save" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="frm">

    <div id="validation-error"></div> < -- div where I want feed back  posted

    <h2>Enter Web Address:</h2>
    <input type="text" name="url" value="" size="75" /> <br>

    <div><input type="submit" onclick="javascript:makeAjaxCall();" id="submit_frm" value="Submit" /></div>

    </form>
</div><!-- /adding_urls  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/testing/js/another_method.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, using a form element for an ajax call is no needed. You can remove form tag and change the submit by a simple button, that has to call to your ajax function. Your problem here is that you are submiting a form, and you won't to do that

Comment: @kmsdev - on the other hand, removing the form tags means you can't just do `$(form).serialize()`, you'd have to parse the form yourself, which is why a form is a good idea, but the submit event should be caught as there are many ways to submit a form, and listening for just a click on a button is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @adeneo I think that in this case you are right totally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline event handler (the `javascript:makeAjaxCall()` thing) and do

```
$('#frm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url      : "http://localhost/testing/index.php/urlsaving/jquery_save",
        cache    : false,
        data     : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        type     : "post",
        success  : function( data ){
            $('#validation-error').html(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the event:

```
function makeAjaxCall(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax...
}
```

You could also simply change the submit button into a regular button `<button>` or `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="makeAjaxCall();"/>`

Then remove the click handler from the markup:

```
<input id="ajaxButton" type="button" value="Submit" />

$('#ajaxButton').on('click', makeAjaxCall);
```